# {syntax] adding variable after class to JS

Tags: javascript, php

my question is so simple. you see vertical-center-4 class.I want to add  $settings['...'] php variable to last of vertical-center-4 class.In other words, I want to use php variable like uniq id because it gives likely random numbers depend user settings.

with pseudo codes:

$('.vertical+center-4 + $settings['show_post_per_page...'] ).slick

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.vertical-center-4').slick({
                    centerMode: false,
                    slidesToShow: <?php echo $settings['show_posts_per_page_at_the_same_time']; ?>,
                    infinite: true,
```

Comment: why you give me negative points?

Comment: the question is smilar to multiple class using in js

Comment: How about this: let unique = "<?php echo $settings['show_post_per_page']; ?>"; then unique = unique.toString() and then $('.vertical-center-4' + unique).slick

Comment: thanks, it works.can you write your comment as an asnwer so I can click answered button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create js variable from php variable

```
let unique = "<?php echo $settings['show_post_per_page']; ?>";
unique = unique.toString();
```

then concatenate with class name

```
$('.vertical-center-4' + unique).slick
```